Adding Solution to TFS assigns unexpected local workspace
Ok, we use TFS (Azure Dev Ops) on-prem for source control.  When I create a new SSIS project in VS and go to add it to Source Control, I want it in the existing Architecture folder and the "add screen" looks like this:

I click OK and it adds it where I wanted it, but the local path/workspace assigned to it is actually the path to the actual project.  Why would it not inherit the local path from the Architecture folder like other items do?  Note the difference in Local Path in the two images below.
Test Project where Local Path = Path to the Project

Note the Local Path to the parent folder.  That is the Local Path/workspace I have assigned in TFS when I connected.

I would expect the Local Path to inherit. I should have the "copy" that is in TFS (mapped to the Local Path/Workspace) and my existing local/physical copy.
What is going on here?  I know I can change the Local Path/Workspaces, but that doesn't really resolve my issue.  Trying to understand why it is working this way.

When you add a solution to source control in Visual Studio, it creates a mapping between the server path (e.g., $/test/Architecture/testproject) and your local path (e.g., C:\Users\username\source\repos\testproject).
You can check the local path and source location mapping in the page:

Or you can check the map relationship by right clicking the project folder > advanced > properties or removing mapping.

It just creates map relationship and will not copy the code to your workspace. This will not affect the source control and should be a designed behavior.
